# c++ Overload Assignment operator of class with pointers to other class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have a Network class which contains pointers. I want to overload assignment operator for it.

```
class Network
{
public:
    Network();

    Layer *Layers;      //The total layers in network
    unsigned long net_tot_layers;   //Number of layers
    unsigned long *net_layers;      //Array which tells no. of neurons in each layer
    Network::Network(double learning_rate, unsigned long layers[], unsigned long tot_layers);
};
```

Constructor

```
Network::Network(double learning_rate, unsigned long layers[], unsigned long tot_layers) {
    net_layers = new unsigned long[tot_layers]; //Initialize the layers array
    Layers = new Layer[tot_layers];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < tot_layers; i++) {
        net_layers[i] = layers[i];
        Layers[i].Initialize(layers[i]); //Initialize each layer with the specified size
    }

    net_tot_layers = tot_layers;
}
```

How to overload assignment operator for it correctly with deep copy?

Please help, want to replace all pointers with vectors...

```
class Layer
{
public:
    Layer();
    ~Layer();
    Neuron *Neurons;
    void Initialize(unsigned long size);    
};

class Neuron
{
public:
    Neuron();   // Constructor
    ~Neuron();  // Destructor

    Link* Links;    //Links
    Neuron();   // Constructor
};
class Link {
public:
    Link(double weight = 0.0); // Constructor
    ~Link();    // Distructor
    double weight;  //Weight of the link

};
```

To replace all pointers with vectors, what changes/additions I have to make>

Comment: use vector, you will save yourself hours and hours.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Have some more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one. Replace the dynamic arrays with `std::vector`s. All done.

Can't do that? Cannibalize your constructor and rather than setting the member variables to the input parameters, set the members equal to the source Network.

```
Network & Network::operator=(const Network & src) {
    net_tot_layers = src.net_tot_layers;

    // make new arrays
    net_layers = new unsigned long[net_tot_layers]; 
    Layers = new Layer[net_tot_layers];

    // copy from source Network to this network
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < net_tot_layers ; i++) {
        net_layers[i] = src.net_layers[i];
        Layers[i] = src.Layers[i]; // and make damn sure Layer also has an operator=
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Step 1 redux:

All of the dynamic arrays have been replaced by std::vector. Note the ordering because this is important. A class contained by a vector must be fully defined before defining the vector. Forward declaration is not good enough here.

```
class Link {
public:
    Link(double weight = 0.0); // Constructor
    ~Link();    // Distructor
    double weight;  //Weight of the link

};

class Neuron
{
public:
    Neuron();   // Constructor
    ~Neuron();  // Destructor

    std::vector<Link> Links;
    Neuron();   // Constructor
};

class Layer
{
public:
    Layer();
    ~Layer();
    std::vector<Neuron> Neurons;
    void Initialize(unsigned long size);    
};

class Network
{
public:
    Network();

    std::vector<Layer> Layers;      //The total layers in network
    std::vector<unsigned long> net_layers; //Array which tells no. of neurons in each layer

    Network::Network(double learning_rate, unsigned long layers[], unsigned long tot_layers);
};
```

Note: `unsigned long net_tot_layers;` has been removed because it is no longer necessary. `Layers` and `net_layers` are now vectors and vectors know their length.

Next, items are placed, copied, into a vector using a number of different ways ([See documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). Usually the place_back method is used, adding elements one by one. In the network case, the number of Layers in the vector is known, so there is a slightly faster option:

```
Network::Network(double learning_rate, 
                 unsigned long layers[], 
                 unsigned long tot_layers): Layers(tot_layers),
                                            net_layers(tot_layers){
```

The bit after the colon is a member initializer list. This is a really cool C++ feature I wish they taught in school more often. It allows you to initialize members of the class *before* the constructor body is run. This makes sure that all of the pieces are in place before they are needed and often has some performance advantages. `Layers(tot_layers)` calls the vector constructor and tells it to allocate space for `tot_layers` `Layer`s. `net_layers(tot_layers)` does the same thing for `net_layers`.

An aside: `net_layers` probably shouldn't be in `Network`. This is a property of `Layer`, and `Layer` should keep track of it. (It already does because vector `Neurons` knows it's length). I recommend

```
unsigned long Layer::GetNumNeurons()
{
    return Neurons.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: Have sone more questions